# Monitoring a specific database with pg_isready

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

How do I monitor a specific db with pg_isready?

Instance : DBSPG10T1   Version : 10.14     Port : 6241

```
postgres@postgres # SELECT datname FROM pg_database;
  datname
-----------
 postgres
 template1
 template0
 dbspg10t1

[postgres@HOSTNAME ~]$ if pg_isready -d postgres://localhost:6241/dbspg10t1; then echo "200 OK"; else echo "500 NOT OK"; fi
localhost:6241 - accepting connections
200 OK
```

The DB test does not exists but pg_isready still returns ok.

```
[postgres@HOSTNAME ~]$ if pg_isready -d postgres://localhost:6241/test; then echo "200 OK"; else echo "500 NOT OK"; fi
localhost:6241 - accepting connections
200 OK
```

Is this a syntax issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this might be a known bug. `pg_isready` doesn't use common code to the `psql` utility. See this pgsql-hackers thread on the topic from 2013: [Re: -d option for pg_isready is broken](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/52840D38.9070604%40agliodbs.com).

Without diving too far into it, the relevant quotes seem to be...

> > Why aren't we using the exact same code as psql?  Why does pg_isready
> > have its own code for this?
>
> Because pg_isready wants to print the host and port we actually tried
> to connect to, which no other utility does.  Turns out, there's no
> clean API for that.  We tried to invent something, but the evidence
> seems to indicate that what we invented bites.

But why wasn't it changed?

> ...the whole point of having both host and
> hostaddr seems to be that you can lie about where you're connecting.
> If you set host=some.pretty.domain.name hostaddr=1.2.3.4, the point is
> to say that you're connecting to the first while, under the covers,
> actually connecting to the second.  Now, I am unclear what value this
> has, but someone at some point evidently thought it was a good idea,
> so we need to be careful about changing it.

To be fair, this is based on a very cursory reading of that one thread, but for your purposes, I think it's safe to treat this as a known bug

```bash
bash-4.4$ pg_isready
/tmp:5432 - accepting connections

bash-4.4$ pg_isready -d postgres://127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1:5432 - accepting connections

bash-4.4$ pg_isready -d postgres://127.0.0.1/foo
127.0.0.1:5432 - accepting connections

bash-4.4$ psql postgres://127.0.0.1/foo
psql: error: FATAL:  database "foo" does not exist

bash-4.4$
```

Comment: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/scripts/pg_isready.c